# How to get soft touch matte finish on my resin cast parts?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, plastic

I'm working on a prototype electronic consumer product for which I intend to use silicone molds with polyurethane casting to get the plastic body. I have seen a few products with a smooth satin finish which almost feels like rubber to touch but is actually plastic. Requesting advice on achieving similar surface finish.

Comment: I believe the surface finish of the mold in which the silicone is cast will determine the surface finish of the final part.